# Python numpy comparing two 3D Arrays for similarity

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to compare two 3D numpy arrays to calculate similarity. I have found these two posts, which I am trying to stich together to something useful.

- [Comparing NumPy Arrays for Similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908407/comparing-numpy-arrays-for-similarity)
- [Subtracting numpy arrays of different shape efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677183/subtracting-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape-efficiently)

To make a long story short, I have two arrays created from 3D point clouds so they are filled with 3D coordinates, but because the 3D objects are different, the arrays have different lengths.

If requested, I can post some sample arrays, but they are +1000 points, so that would be a lot of text to post.

Here is what I am trying to do now.  You can get `array1` and `array2` data here: https://pastebin.com/WbNvRUwG (`array2` starts at line 1858).

```
array1 = [long np array with 3D coordinates]
array2 = [long np array with 3D coordinates]

array1_original = array1.copy()
if len(array1) < len(array2):
        array1, array2 = array2, array1
array_difference = np.subtract(array1, array2[:,None]) # The [:,None] is from the second link to make the arrays have same length to enable subtractraction
array_abs_difference = np.absolute(array_difference)
array_total_difference = np.sum(array_abs_difference)
similarity = 1 - (array_total_difference / 
np.sum(array1_original))
```

My array differences are fine and represent what I want, so the most similar arrays have small differences, but when I do the sum of `array1_original` it comes out way smaller than my differences and therefore my similarity score becomes negative.

I also tried to calculate the difference from an array filled with zeros to `array1_original`, but it comes out about the same.

Can anyone tell me why `np.sum(array1_original)` would not be bigger than `np.sum(array_abs_difference)`?

Comment: Posted a link to a pastebin with the two arrays data

Comment: I see now that my method is flawed and will mostly always result in the difference being bigger because the objects are never the same size. Is there another way of getting a normalized similarity score between two arrays?

Comment: You need a definition of "similarity" as a starting point

Comment: Please put a small reproducible data code **in the body** of the question and show what will be the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy comparison ended up being to slow, so I just used open3D instead. It works for me